# Control All the open tabs in JSF with Primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I need to automatic logout and send me to loging page. I made this via IddleMonitor of primefaces:

```
  <h:form prependId="false">
            <p:idleMonitor timeout="300000">
             <p:ajax event="idle" listener="#{mainController.timeout()}" />
            </p:idleMonitor> 
    </h:form>
```

Where maincontroller.timeout:

```
   public void timeout() throws IOException
{

    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
            .redirect("/cas/logout");
}
```

Everything is Ok. But the problem is when two or more tabs are open in the browser. The iddlemonitor only will execute for the first tab. And the other tab will maintain open but with the session already closed. I want when the first tab fire it. All the tabs fire the event of logout. Any approach of doing this? Also I'm using Java EE 6 with JSF 2.2 and Primefaces 3.4

Comment: Did you try [polling](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/poll.xhtml)?

Comment: Are you ultimately trying to say that timeout should only be occurred in the current tab/window and all other tabs/windows having the same page opened should be notified by the timeout event and this should all happen only in the current HTTP session? (You are probably going wrong. Logout should happen only once in the current session, when timeout occurs and all other tabs/windows having the same page opened should only be notified and redirected to a desired page (login). Notifications can be sent using "Push").

Comment: on oncomplete of the timeout send a message to other pages to redirect using https://github.com/jcubic/sysend.js

Comment: @Tiny Yeah that is what I want, but how to use push? I will try  using that script

Comment: Uh! I have not yet tried [`<p:socket>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/notify.xhtml). The showcase example uses PrimeFaces 5.2.x (and Eclipse Jetty) that should match your environment.